# How to change dom element in ajax way but not replace the dom content using javascript way

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

By default the page will show  `up vote button`

After user click `up button`, the page will reload again then show `down vote button`

Now I want to do it in Ajax way without loading the page,

But how could I change the button without reloading the page ?

```
  - if not comment.has_evaluation?(:votes, current_user)
    = link_to vote_comment_path(comment, type: "up"), method: :post do
      %button.btn.btn-xs.btn-success
        Like this
  - else
    = link_to vote_comment_path(comment, type: "down"), method: :post do
      %button.btn.btn-xs.btn-danger
        Unlike this
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use background image to control the `up vote` and `down vote` buttons. Try this:

```
var $btn = $('#btn-id');
$.ajax({
    url: '/rate',
    data: {key: value},
    type: 'post'
}).done(function(res) {
    if (res.success) {
       if (res.myRate.up) {
           $btn.removeClass('down-vote-bg');
           $btn.addClass('up-vote-bg');
       } else {
           $btn.removeClass('up-vote-bg');
           $btn.addClass('down-vote-bg');
       }
    }
}).fail(function() {
    alert('Action failed');
});
```

Check [jQuery Ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more information.